# adding line breaks in PHP with custom fields

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-helper, break

I don't know very much about PHP so I'm afraid of trying something I found online and wanted to consult the experts first.

I installed a customized billing field plugin so I can add extra billing information captured during checkout.

I didn't want the  table in there because it gets in the way of copying and pasting the information to my vendor and the author gave me a PHP file that removes it. However, when I looked at the code of the updated PHP, it still has the table on there so I don't know exactly what was done, but now all the fields are all jammed together in a paragraph. How can I put a line break in between each custom field?

This is the part of the code that would product the information on the receipt.

```html
<table width="100%">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
                             <th width="50%" ><?php echo $billing_field['label']; ?>:</th>
                             <td width="50%" ><?php echo $billingkeyvalue; ?></td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
</table>
```

**I tried asking the author about it but this question literally has spanned over 3 months because the author did not reply back to me  the first two and I have a feeling it might happen again so I rather see if I can get a quick help vs. Googling and destroying my site or waiting another 3 months for help from the author...

Answer (score 0):

With `CSS` you can override normal table behavior, and place every table element in new line.

```css
table, tbody, tr, th, td {
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th width="50%" >billing_field:</th>
   <td width="50%" >billingkeyvalue</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It wouldn't put the table back in the codes with the CSS you provided, would it?

Comment: I tried adding the CSS style and it partially broke my site. :( Made certain features unusable.... like finishing the order.

Comment: I have used global selectors for this example such as `table, tbody, tr, th, td`, you can target specific table in your `HTML Dom` with more precise CSS selectors, targeting by `id`, `class` or something else

Comment: I think that's beyond my skill set. :( Thanks for your help anyways.